# The system.webServer/security/authorization in my IIS 7 web.config is not working

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, authorization

In the root of my Admin folder, I have the following in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authorization>
                    <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                    <add accessType="Allow" users="" roles="Admin" />
        </authorization>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This is almost verbatim from [IIS documentation](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authorization/add), but I changed the role to be "Admin" instead of "Administrators",because that's the role in my app.

I have ensured that the ASP.NET UrlAuthorization module is not running via a `<remove name="UrlAuthorization" />` in the `modules` element of my root web.config.   I just installed IIS7 UrlAuthorization, so I know it is running.

The problem is that even though I explicitly allow the Admin role and have validated my Admin user is logged in, the Admin gets an unauthorized error.  What am I misunderstanding?

*Note, since I started writing this questions, I resolved the issue my explicitly enumerating every disallowed role and removing the `remove users="*"`, but I don't know why it worked.*

Comment: When you remove that rule, allow access to everyone, login as that admin user, does the HttpContext.User show that user to be in the expected role? Also, did you try setting the equivalent within system.web/authorization (that's where I do it, and it works at IIS7 for me)?

Comment: Yes, the admin is logged in, I have confirmed that with a `Response.Write(User.IsInRole("Admin"));`.  Yes, I tried using system.web and registering the UrlAuthorization module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's going to be an answer to this.  But in case anyone else runs across the same issue, I ended up having to change my approach and manage security externally from the ASP.NET pipeline.